# What is the correct and most formal way to say "since it fulfills", "as it satisfies" or "meet" the conditions?

Tags: vocabulary

My university asks me to include this text on my thesis:

```
Prof. Dr. XXX, as director of the doctoral thesis YYY
by Mr. ZZZ in..., authorizes for submission since it has
the conditions necessary for its defence.
```

But I think it doesn't sound well.

Should I make any changes to improve it?

```
Prof. Dr. XXX, as director of the doctoral thesis YYY by
Mr. ZZZ in the..., authorizes for its submission since/as
it meets/fulfills/satisfies the conditions necessary/required
for its defence.
```

I also don't know if have to suppress that "for" nor if I should write "necessary conditions".

Comment: I would never correct an awkward formula. You use it and move on.

Comment: I agree with Yosef. If your professor instructs you to include that in your thesis, then you should include the text without any modification.

Comment: I live in a foreign country, and most of my teachers speak English even worse than me. Many of their writings seem to be written by a child.

Comment: *My university asks me to include this text on my thesis:* The that is what you do. I assume that they will be awarding th4e doctorate.